# AngularJS Promises with Synchronous Http calls

Tags: angularjs, http, synchronous

I am facing an issue with the `then` function not being called in one of my controllers when doing multiple synchronous http calls.

In the below code, the `console.log(data)` statement in my controller is not being executed as the control never comes to the `then` function.

********************controller file

```
function MyController($scope, $location, $timeout) {

    function submit($event) {
      Myservice.getDetails(productid).then(function(data){
        console.log(data) 
      });
    } 


angular.module('myModule')
    .controller('MyController', MyController);
})(window.angular);
```

******************  MyService

```
(function (angular, mySecondService) {
  'use strict';

  function MyService($http, $q, $log, $location, mySecondService{

    function getDetails(pId) {
      byodCheckerData = [];
      mySecondService.httpTkn().then(function(Tkn){
          var request = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'getDetails',
            headers: {auth: Tkn},
            params: {Id:pId}
          };

          return $http(request).then(function(resp){
            return resp;
          })                
      })              
    }; 

    return {
      getDetails: getDetails;
  }

angular.module('myModule')
.factory('MyService', MyService);

})(window.angular);
```

*********************************** MySecondservice

```
(function (angular) {
  'use strict';
  function mySecondService($log, $http, $q) { 
    var ts = this;
      function httpTkn(){
          defer = $q.defer();
          var authReq = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'getTkn'
          };
         return $http(authReq).then(function (response) {
              defer.resolve(response.data.tkn
        return response.data.tkn;
            },
            function (error) {

              return error;
            });
      };


    ts.httpTkn = httpTkn;
  }

  angular.module('myModule')
    .service('mySecondService', mySecondService);

})(angular);.
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try below code :

```
function getDetails(pId) {
    var defered = $q.defer();
    byodCheckerData = [];
    mySecondService.httpTkn().then(function(Tkn) {
        var request = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'getDetails',
            headers: { auth: Tkn },
            params: { Id: pId }
        };

        $http(request).then(function(resp) {
            defered.resolve(resp);
        });
    });
    return defered.promise;
}
```

Note that , you need to return promise so that the function works when the `$http` values is resolved

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This worked for me. Thanks Shashank. Not sure if i can ask this here but if you don't mind, how would we write a karma test case for this scenario(Synchronous nested http calls).

Comment: Do u mean test case of `controller` where you'll have to create a mock service with method `getDetails` ???

Comment: Yes please. I have written test case to check behaviour of get details function using mock service . If we want to test the synchronous functionality like second http call waits till first http call completes.